# how to query through this tables structure

Tags: mysql, join

Hello I have a `products` table having fields

```
     products_id,products_number,products_status,products_price
```

where `products_id` is `auto_increment` and `PRIMARY_KEY`.

I have other table `products_description` having fields

```
 products_id,language_id,products_description,products_name
```

Where `products_id and language_id` or composite primary key. Remember `products_id` is the same as in `products` table. Now in `products_description` table there are more than one record against one `products_id` with respect to different `language_id`.

**My Problem**

I have to get all columns from `products` table and `products_name` column from `products_description` table. I have applied simple join query like this

```
SELECT p.products_id,p.products_model,p.products_price,p.products_status,pd.products_name FROM products p, products_description pd WHERE p.products_id=pd.products_id
```

but I know this query is wrong as it is returning more than one rows against one product if it is having more than one record in `products_description` table.

**What I Want**

I want to fetch one record from `products_description` against each `products_id` of products`table table if no`language_id`is given in query. I know that it can be done if I apply`language_id` condition in query. But is there any way to get the records

Comment: 1. how would you know which product_description is correct if you have more than one?  2. Did you try group by on products_id ?

Comment: Does it matter which description you get?  So the product name, status, price could all be in one language and the description in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumes that any description returned will be fine.
uses a correlated sub-query on products_description  to get the min value language ID for a related products_ID

```
select p.products_id, p.products_number,p. products_status,p. products_price
       pd.language_id, pd.products_description, pd.products_name
from   products p, 
       products_description pd,
       (Select min(Language_ID) mLID 
        from products_Description ipd 
        where PD.Products_ID=ipd.products_ID 
          and ipd.language_ID = pd.language_ID) A
where  p.products_id  = pd.products_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.*, 
       pd.products_name
from products   p,
      products_description pd
where p.products_id = pd.products_id
and   pd.language_id = 
        (select min(language_id)
          from products_description pd2
          where pd.products_id = pd2.products_id)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: you would have to get the min 1st then do the join.  You can't group by products_name as they will all be different.